# Why are there such differences in performance between a LINQ query vs. Advanced.LuceneQuery?

Tags: ravendb

There reason I ask is that I had been using the strongly typed version, but ran into the issue of it not being flexible enough, so I switched over to the AdvancedQuery.Luncene which did provide the flexibility but at a loss in performance. I was thinking that the lower level query engine would be faster than than it counter-part or at least equivalent. Can someone shed some light on this?

Thank you,
Stephen

```
watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        result = s.Query<Product>()
            .Statistics(out stats)
            .Where(x => x.HasPicture == true)
            .ToArray();
watch.Stop();
```

Time elapsed to execute query for HasPicture == true 975

Total number of products found: 412352

```
watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
result = s.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Product>("Products_Index")
            .Statistics(out stats)
            .Where("HasPicture:(True)")
            .ToArray()
            ;

watch.Stop();
```

Time elapsed to execute query with Lucene 7065

Total number of products found: 412352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Itamar.

The problem was the Where clause, when using the LuceneQuery use WhereEquals.

```
 result = s.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Product>("Products_Index")
                    .Statistics(out stats)
                    .WhereEquals("HasPicture", true)
                    .ToArray()
                    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pick performance battle when you have a deviation from the standard performance baseline. I would start with out-of-the-box setting, collect data, measure, rinse and repeat. If unacceptable  performance degradation is observed then take action based on your observations then change one thing, collect data, measure... So the answer is OOB settings first.

Comment: Peter, I shed some light on the subject.